# Can I get free HTTPs for a GitHub page + namechap with Let's Encrypt?

Tags: https, github, namecheap

I have a GitHub page  and I have a domain from namecheap. Now I've heard that [Let's Encrypt](https://letsencrypt.org/) offers free certificates.

Is it possible to make my site use HTTPS? How?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't suggest to use letsencrypt, because it contains plenty of bugs, [read their own Disclaimer](https://github.com/letsencrypt/letsencrypt#disclaimer)

Instead you can use [cloudflare for github pages](https://www.goyllo.com/github/pages/free-cloudflare-ssl-for-custom-domain/).

By d way, I just wrote this article, after reading your post. Thanks :)

Comment: You realise CloudFlare has a [disclaimer too](https://www.cloudflare.com/terms/), right? They don't promise anything is stable or guaranteed to work, and as with all 'free' services you get your money's worth.

Comment: I am using cloudflare from 8 months, and I am not facing any problem, I write my answer based on my experience.

Comment: *[Kloudsec](https://kloudsec.com) solves the problem of getting custom domained Github Pages to HTTPS*. See [Kloudsec for Github Pages](https://kloudsec.com/github-pages).

Comment: I think it is worth noting - https://konklone.com/post/github-pages-now-sorta-supports-https-so-use-it - ```Until GitHub Pages or CloudFlare fix things, you'll only be able to encrypt the connection between the user and CloudFlare. The connection between CloudFlare and GitHub Pages will need to remain in plaintext, using CloudFlare's "Flexible SSL" option.```

Comment: They also provide end to end encryption (Full SSL) as well. But I don't think we need it for security purpose, since our website is static so, there is nothing to inject :)

Comment: As far as I understand, they don't give end to end encryption. See https://docs.kloudsec.com/discuss/576b9ce2de333e0e00d0a934.

Answer (score 3):

To make use of a certificate you not only need to have your own domain and certificate but you need to have access to the server configuration so that you actually could use the certificate. In case of github you don't have such deep access so you cannot make use of any certificate, no matter if you got it through Let's Encrypt or some other CA.